# Digitizing without gaps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, features, snapping

I started making a vector layer from raster data but I see slivers (gap area) between my parks and roads layer. How can I overcome this problem? I planned to make a map with scale 1:5000.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The title of your question was misleading. Your issue is more probably about **snapping**, which is one of the several tools used for digitizing features.

Simply, enable snapping mode from `Settings >> Snapping Options...`.

Then, try to use the `Node Tool` and the `Move Feature(s)` tools from the main QGIS window (they are activated once you have set the layer in editing mode):

[image]

These are only general rules and are necessary for starting the digitizing operation: if you need a more specific answer, please edit the question for adding more information or ask a new separate question if you encounter any problem after having applied these suggestions.

---

For more information, you may have a look at [this](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#setting-the-snapping-tolerance-and-search-radius) paragraph from the [QGIS Documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/index.html).

Comment: @Yogi2296 You're welcome! Glad it helped.

Comment: another question.What is the function of avoid intersection ?? i am new in QGIS.i already tried using it for my park layer,but it seems nothing change @mgri

Comment: @Yogi2296, I'm not sure, but `Avoid intersections` should only work when digitizing new features. It does not work at all with existing features. If I remember well, it allows to quickly digitize a new polygon without worrying about snapping exactly to the neighboring polygons. Maybe some test could solve your doubts :)